# Castle.Core.4.1.1 to .NET 4.5.2

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, castle-dynamicproxy

In VS2015 I have a .NET 4.5.2 console app and I when I try to install nuget package `Castle.Core 4.1.1` I get this weird error:

> Could not install package '**System.Collections.Specialized 4.3.0**'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=**v4.5.2**', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Why is that? How can I install the package to such projects?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. 
If you look here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core/4.1.1
 you will see that Castle.Core for net452 does not have any dependencies. 
Did you do any retargetting? 
Can you provide more detailed steps about what you tried.

Comment: Hmm it turned out I used some wrong local package source with wrong package... Just tried a new Console app and added Castle.Core from nuget.org and it worked.

Comment: @imps don't know why but when I push nuget.org's package to our internal server, dependencies become different